# Paypal Invoicing API, SendInvoiceRequest returns invoice null error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the C# SDK for our implementation (Classic API).

I can create an invoice fine, but whenever I try to send an invoice the response comes back with an error "Invalid request parameter: invoice cannot be null".

```
var result = new SendInvoiceResult();
var service = new PayPal.Invoice.InvoiceService(PayPalConfig());
var envelopeRequest = new RequestEnvelope
{
    errorLanguage = "en_US", detailLevel = DetailLevelCode.RETURNALL
};
var request = new SendInvoiceRequest ( envelopeRequest, invoiceId );
var response = service.SendInvoice(request);
```

If I use the CreateAndSendInvoice method instead then a similar thing happens - the invoice gets created (I can view the URLs and the invoice shows as in draft) but it never sends.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the complete response from the PayPal including the correlation id ?

Comment: I can tell you the correlation Id is 3f10118c7b2d9, I can't get the complete response as that gets handled by the SDK and right now I can't seem to get that far into the source code to see it. Thanks.